# How can I pass a list of objects in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm working on small project that makes short links from full URLs, but I have an issue. How can I do a "GET" method that will return a list of my objects? I wrote a "POST" method, but when I tried to write the same thing I got error and my request required to use `full_url` to get data.

Model class:

```
class Links(models.Model):
    full_url = models.URLField(unique=True)
    short_url = models.CharField(
        max_length=20,
        unique=True,
        db_index=True,
        blank=True
    )
    requests_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-created_at'),

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.short_url:
            while True:
                self.short_url = ''.join(
                    random.choices(
                        settings.CHARACTERS,
                        k=settings.TOKEN_LENGTH
                    )
                )
                if not Links.objects.filter(
                    short_url=self.short_url
                ).exists():
                    break
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f'{self.short_url} -> {self.full_url}'
```

another function from views.py:

```
class LinkAPIView(APIView):
    authentication_classes = [JWTAuthentication]
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    
    def post(self, request):
        serializer = LinkSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            token, status_code = serializer.create(
                validated_data=serializer.validated_data
            )
            return Response(LinkSerializer(token).data, status=status_code)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: It will be smth like this, but need to remove index at Links.objects.all[]


def get(self, request):
        serializer = GetLinksSerializer(Links.objects.all()[2], data=request.data, partial=True)
        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            return Response({
            'status' : status.HTTP_200_OK,
            'data' : serializer.data
            })
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is fixed my problem

```
def get(self, request):
    serializer = GetLinksSerializer(Links.objects.all(), many=True)
    return Response({
        'status' : status.HTTP_200_OK,
        'data' : serializer.data
    })
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).